# Saving data with a variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to save the number of clicks for further output. In general, the goal is as follows: the number of clicks and the date/time are saved. Then it will all be displayed in the statistics. By date and quantity. Well, this is later) Now it is necessary to save.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const StartPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StartPage> createState() => _StartPageState();
}

class _StartPageState extends State<StartPage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter(){
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30
                ),
              ),
          ButtonTheme(
            minWidth: 220.0,
            height: 220.0,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _incrementCounter();
              },
              child: Text("Тыкать носом", style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 15
              ),),
            ),
          )
            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I thought to implement it on SQLite, but I have no idea how to save data with a variable for further output

Comment: Well if you're gonna save it then have to tried firebase firestore/ realtime.

Comment: Will he be able to save the date + quantity?

Comment: You can save admin.firestore.Timestamp.now(); as such as far as timestamp regardless of users location along with data while saving it.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Shared Preferences to save the input.

```
 // Obtain shared preferences.
 final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

 // Save an integer value to 'counter' key. 
 await prefs.setInt('counter', 10);
 // Save an boolean value to 'repeat' key. 
 await prefs.setBool('repeat', true);
 // Save an double value to 'decimal' key. 
 await prefs.setDouble('decimal', 1.5);
 // Save an String value to 'action' key. 
 await prefs.setString('action', 'Start');
 // Save an list of strings to 'items' key. 
 await prefs.setStringList('items', < String > ['Earth', 'Moon', 'Sun']);
```